# PHP + PostgreSQL + ODBC - UTF8 - diacritic problem

Tags: php, postgresql, utf-8, odbc

I use official pgsqlodbc and I have diacritic problem

example: "P�edplatn� za �ervenec 2019"

(black question mark is error, correct is "Předplatné za červenec 2019")

But, data in DB is correct with my language diacritics mark (I tested with ODBC Devart and everything is ok - but Devart is not free (i tested on trial).

When I check DB using Valentina Studio it tells me:

> Collation Settings: Encoding UTF8

The DB is remote, I have access only via VPN with help Valentina Studio and PHP. Its remote company, i can not change anything in DB.
Now I run the aplication on localhost (Win10, Laragon, Wordpress, SAGE template). I must use ODBC, because I must connect to remote DB via VPN (I use SSH tunnel with help Putty). But! I wrote aboce, with another ODBC driver (Devart) is everything OK. So, I want repair setting for connect with help free official ODBC from Postgre.

My Code:

```
$dsn ="DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64);Description=Free;Data Source=localhost;Port=5433;Database=$db_customer;User ID=$user;Schema=$schema;sslmode=require;";
```

I tested also DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) - same error

```
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);

$sql="SELECT IH.publi.....

$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

...odbc_fetch_row($rs)... etc. classic
```

Can somobedy help me with wrong diacritis? How/where can I set encoding UTF8? I spent hours for solving and nothing.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC with PHP? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thank you for your help. But, is it relevant, when in case another ODBC driver (Devart) is everything OK? However... now I run the aplication on localhost (Win10, Laragon, Wordpress, SAGE template). I must use ODBC, because I must connect to remote DB via VPN (I use SSH tunnel with help Putty). Without ODBC I am not able connect to remote Postgre via VPN. But! I wrote above, with another ODBC driver (Devart) is everything OK. So, I want repair setting for connect with help free official ODBC from Postgre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not logic in my case(DB is not in Win1250), but its function. Diacritic is OK.

```
$invoice_item["nazev"] = iconv( "CP1250", "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $invoice_item["nazev"]);
```